# Exit current command in cmd.exe

Tags: php, symfony, cmd

It is really a stupid question, but the main reason I cant find an answer is that I dont find the best keywords to put in search engines.

When I write a command for example: `php app/console`, and the command is not giving a result, how can I come back to the command line (exit the current command)?

How can I go back to the main command line (C:/xampp/htdocs)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try CTRL+C, both on mac and PC

Comment: Perfect, It is working, I will accept after 10 minutes, a requirement by Stackoverflow

Comment: This solution doesn't work well for symfony2 command connected with database (paticularly doctrine update). Rather you should kill your task via PID and in special cases via your database.